# phpmyadmin queries loading or processing without returning any result on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I  just signed up for aws free tier, and have installed my lamp web server as prescribed, the problem is when i open phpmyadmin and run a query it loads or process but doesn.t return a result, Any help please. I have tried create table query and import query.

Comment: show what you are trying to do? perhaps some code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed browser from mozilla to chrome and that solved it.